# Mapping classes c#

Tags: c#

I am writing a tranformer that takes some input and gives an output.I need to call a specific tranformer based on my input type.

```
public static myentrypoint( template t);
{
   //I could do something like this.
   switch(t)
   {
        case t1:
         transformt1(..);
        case t2:
         transformt1(..);
         ....
   }
}

Trasform1 : Itransform
{
    tranform1(...);
}

Trasform2 : Itransform
{
    tranform2(...);
}
```

I need to map which function to call based on what my template is. I can do a switch but are there more cleaner ways to do this using some design patterns ? I was thinking a of writing a static dictionary. I am new to OOP so any suggestions would be great.

Comment: What is `template`? Is it an enum?

Comment: Its another class , there could be different types of templates all derived from a base template

Comment: It can‘t be, because then the switch wouldn‘t work.

Comment: I think your question is too generic to get any great responses. You can handle what you are talking about in so many different ways and the way you choose will depend on your requirements.

Comment: I could use if else by checking what type it is.

Comment: My requirement is , I should be able to add new tranforms and new templates without modifying existing code, but by extending

Comment: @Sefe Why not? He could use nameof or override ToString() and use that...

Comment: @DeanKuga: He could do a lot of things, but he doesn‘t. The code makes no sense and you can guess what the OP wants. And how would nameof help when the object is nor accepted in the switch?

Comment: A premise to answering this question is that you don't want to receive a parameter and then have to inspect it to see what type you have. If you have to do that, something has likely gone wrong. If you pass type `Template` to a method, the method shouldn't need to know any more about the type than that it's a `Template`. So there's more to the answer then just this method. If you provide a little more detail on what you're trying to do it might be easier to apply some sort of pattern to it. It just needs a little more context.

Answer (score 1):

If template is a class, and each template potentially has a different transform, then why not just include the transform function inside of your template class?

```
public static myentrypoint( ITemplate t);
{
   t.transform();
}
```

Comment: This might make sense but it might also violate the Single Responsibility Principle. It might not be within the responsibility of the class to transform itself.

Comment: @ScottHannen given the detail of the question it is hard to say what the responsibility of the template class would be, but it is a good point worth considering. Even so, It doesn't need to take responsibility for it. The transform may be in it's public interface, but the actual implementation could still be in a separate Transform class that the template "has". This way the same transform could be used for several different templates.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I do these types of situations is through the use of [Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/index). ([Shameless self-promotion of a blog post](http://www.anexinet.com/blog/generic-restrictions-fit-code/))

Basically, you'll have your base class set up like this:

```
public abstract class Transformer<T>
    where T : Template
{
    public abstract void Transform(T item);
}
```

Then you derive for each of your types like this:

```
public class Transformer1 : Tansformer<Template1>
{
    public void Transform(Template1 item) 
    {

    }
}

public class Transformer2 : Transformer<Template2>
{
    public void Transform(Template2 item)
    {

    }
}
```

Then you'll just need a [factory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx) to give you the correct `Transformer`.

```
public class TransformFactory
{
    public Transformer<T> GetTransformer<T>(T item)
    {
        if (item is Template1)
            return new Transformer1();
        else if (item is Template2)
            return new Transformer2();
        // ...
    }
}
```

The benefit of this approach is that you'll be able to encapsulate all behavior on that specific type in the concrete implementations. If there is any common behavior on them all, you can do that in the abstract base.

Answer (score 0):

### Invoking methods based on a parameter without switch-case statements in C#

In **OOP**, based on the [**open**/**close** **principle**] which says that software entities such as classes and functions should be **open** for extension, but **closed**
 for modification.

Methods which use **switch-case statement** would call this principle into question. In order to implement this principle inside the codes without
 causing changes in their functionality.

We use a pattern named **"Delegate Dictionary Pattern"**.

For example, we have an entity named Template that keep input values as well as some of Transform classes for processing this Template.

---

**Template** class for keeping input value

```
public class Template
{
    public int TransformNo { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

**ITransform** interface for transform abstract

```
public interface ITransform
{
    void Do(Template template);
}
```

**Transform1** as a concrete class of ITransform

```
public class Transform1 : ITransform
{
    public void Do(Template template)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Transform : {template.TransformNo}, TemplateTitle : { template.Title}");
    }
}
```

**Transform2** as a concrete class of ITransform

```
public class Transform2 : ITransform
{
    public void Do(Template template)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Transform : {template.TransformNo}, TemplateTitle : { template.Title}");
    }
}
```

**TransformCordinator** class for coordinating template of *ITransformer**

```
public class TransformCordinator
{
    Dictionary<int, Action<Template>> transformMap = new Dictionary<int, Action<Template>>();
    public TransformCordinator()
    {
        transformMap.Add(1, x => new Transform1().Do(x));
        transformMap.Add(2, x => new Transform2().Do(x));
    }

    public void Do(Template template)
    {
        transformMap[template.TransformNo](template);
    }
}
```

// example

```
 class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var transformCordinator = new TransformCordinator();
        transformCordinator.Do(new Template() { TransformNo = 1, Title = "Hi!" });

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: This desgin pattern was Strategy and Event-Delegate Pattern.